# Writing to Excel from Java takes long time for large number of records

Tags: java, jxl

I am using Jxl API to write to Excel,to export large number of records to excel. For my configuration number of records are around 40000. and for before writing these records i have to do lots of computation on fly. there are 16 columns and for 9 columns i am forced to do computation on fly. In a minute it's writing only 2 records to excel, with this speed it is not feasible to write whole data to excel. because with this speed it will take around 12-15 days to complete the process that is not at all acceptable ,can some one suggest any other way i can proceed to finish whole process in 1-2 hours ....!! 
thanks in advance !!

some more info ---

for some columns i am picking the data from db table and adding to sheetData and for other columns for which i am doing computations on fly i am picking data from some db table and calculating the data based on updated input which i got from db tables. for every row and every column input is taking from db tables.

Comment: We need way more information to be able to answer this. Jxl's no slouch, so if you say only 2 rows are written per minute, I'd be inclined to blame your computations - but you have no detail of what the computation involves, which makes it hard to be sure or to help. Please add more detail.

Comment: for some columns i am picking the data from db table and adding to sheetData and for other columns for which i am doing computations on fly i am picking data from some db table and calculating the data based on updated input which i got from db tables. for every row and every column input is taking from db tables.

Comment: I'd be pretty confident the constant querying of the DB is your problem - it's most likely going to be worth your time to look into ways you can reduce the number of queries you're making.

Comment: It seems that the problem lies there. Take the time and measure your application times... :-)

Comment: you mean to say if it is because of DB hits then if i will Export in some other format like CSV or iReport problem will be same ?

Comment: sure! Measuring is easier than arguing about it.

Comment: i Exported in CSV format result is same, takes same time ....

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly difficult to predict the cause of this delay. I would prepare the data first and then time the export processing, in order to get a clear view of the required time for this specific activity .

xls generation takes its time, but 2 records a minute sounds like an overkill. You could also try to generate your xls with [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport). Make a single sheet spreadsheet. iReport is quite quick.

Comment: i don't have much knowledge of iReport, is Exporting in CSV file a good option ?

Comment: That would certainly work too, because Excel can read CSV files directly.